# Securing APIs by IP address - API Platform & Symfony

Tags: symfony, security, api-platform.com, ips

I've got my API made with API platform and Symfony but I'm having problems securing my endpoints.
I have my documentation on the basic URL: api.domaine.com
and access points: /articles/stocks for example.
I have this in my security file:

```
access_control:
        - { path: ^/$, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
        - { path: ^/*, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ips: [ 109.239.112.139, 45.10.152.49 ] }
```

For the documentation, it works well,
and my endpoints are all open even with IP restriction.
I can't understand why my endpoints are open even with the IPS rules.

Do you have an idea?

I tried to work with the roles like this:

```
access_control:
        - { path: ^/$, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
        - { path: ^/*, roles: ROLE_IP_USER, ips: [ 109.239.112.139, 45.10.152.49 ] }
```

and I have also tried this in my entities :

```
#[ApiResource(
    operations: [
        new Get(),
        new GetCollection(),
    ],
    order: ['createdAt' => 'DESC'],
    paginationClientItemsPerPage: true,
    paginationItemsPerPage: 30,
    security: 'is_granted(\'ROLE_IP_USER\')'
)]
```

Comment: Here you go: [How to Use Voters to Check User Permissions](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html).

Comment: `^/*` is zero or more slashes at the beginning. `^/.+` is one or more of any character after the initial slash.

Comment: @ArleighHix I try - { path: ^/.+, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ips: [ 109.239.112.139, 179.132.106.133 ] } but even with an ip not in the list, I have access to the API without any problem, whereas I should be blocked.